# How do you search for other users on the "overflow" sites?

Tags: feature-request, search, users

How do you search for other users on the "overflow" sites?

Comment: have you tried the Users tab (in the header, between "Tags" and "Badges"), and typing their screenname?  how do you want to search that that doesn't allow?  have you seen the search tips? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 11):

Search for other users, eh? Given the date, I assume you mean, "...for romantic purposes". Nudge nudge, wink wink...

It's ok, you can admit it - everyone needs love sooner or later. However, I must caution you: angling for amour on SOFU is a game fraught with danger; sure, these sites might *appear* to be one big meat-market, stacked to the rafters with the lonely and the desperate... and sure, some of the bio photographs are down-right *tantalizing*... *but all is not as it seems*.

#### Uncle Shog's Quick Tips for Avoiding Mating Mishap on SOFU

- **Bio pictures are occasionally retouched** Experts tell us that immediate physical attraction is the single best indicator of emotional compatibility, but crafty hackers often make use of shady tools such as "Photoshop" and "Paint" in their attempts to subvert these reactions. Be on the look out for blurry backgrounds, mis-matched breast sizes and pixilated moustaches - these are dead giveaways for such devious manipulations.
- **Vote-exposition in comments is not necessarily a come-on** Sure, "+1, love it" *sounds* like an open invitation, but SO users are notorious teases. Proceed carefully - leave a follow-up comment complementing one of the user's own answers, and hold out for a stronger response before daring to extend an invitation of an intimate nature.
- **Dirty talk might just be jargon** When chatting up a new acquaintance, colorful euphemisms are a fun way to "get to know each other". On SOFU however, you must always pay careful attention to context: "finger", "poke", "unzip" and "male to female ethernet connector" might not mean what you think...

Comment: "given the date"?  why, what's today?  _*blink*_ _*blink*_ ...what?

Comment: @~quack: Valentine's Day!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit vague. You can search user questions by preceding your typical searches with:

```
user:130154
```

Where the latter number is the userid. For instance, you could find all "greasemonkey" posts by myself by searching:

```
user:130154 greasemonkey
```

If you wanted to look up users by their display name (in whole or in part), you can do so by searching the Users tab at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users - just begin typing in a name, and let the magical ajax take care of the rest.

Comment: @Jonathan: You wouldn't be self promoting your greasemonkey scripts in you last example would you? I'm just joking, I'm using just about all your scripts.

Comment: @Lucas: Not intentionally, but subconsciously...I dunno :)